# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Keynote without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm building an application that has a Keynote model and a Story model (as well as a User model that I implemented with Devise).
Keynotes have many Stories and a Story belongs to a Keynote.

I'm having problems creating new stories and I get the following error:

> **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoriesController#create**
>
> Couldn't find Keynote without an ID

The error happens on line 17 of stories_controller.rb which is

```
@keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])
```

in the create method.

This is part of my stories_controller.rb

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]

  def index
    @keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])
    @stories = @keynote.stories
  end

  def new
    @keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])
    @story = @keynote.stories.build
  end

  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      @keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])
      @story = @keynote.current_user.stories.build(params[:story])
      if @story.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Question submission succeeded'
        redirect_to keynote_stories_path
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my keynotes_controller.rb

```
class KeynotesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @keynotes = Keynote.find :all, :order => 'id ASC'
  end

  def new
    @keynote = Keynote.new
  end

  def show
    @keynote = Keynote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @keynote = Keynote.new(params[:keynote])
    if @keynote.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Keynote submission succeeded'
      redirect_to keynotes_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit:
These are the Parameters when I try to create a new Story.

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"76odSpcfpTlnePxr+WBt36fVdiLD2z+Gnkxt/Eu1/TU=",
>   "story"=>{"name"=>"as"}, 
>   "commit"=>"Send"}

It looks like the ID for the Keynote is not being passed.

This is the view for StoriesController#new

```
<%= error_messages_for 'story' %>

<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
    <p>
        Question:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= submit_tag "Ask" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is what I have in my routes.rb file:

```
  get "keynotes/index"
  get "users/show"
  devise_for :users
  get "votes/create"
  get "stories/index"

  resources :keynotes do
    resources :stories
  end

  resources :stories do
    get 'bin', :on => :collection
    resources :votes
  end

  resources :users

  root :to => 'keynotes#index'
```

Comment: `params[:keynote_id]` is probably `nil` or doesn't exist in the database. Try putting a `puts params[:keynote_id]` to see if you're getting that param correctly. Check that the id exists in the database table as well. Also, are you not getting the error in `StoriesController#new` as well?

Comment: @Zabba right, it look like it's nil but I don't know how to populate it... (see the edit to the post above). Also, where should I put the `puts params[:keynote_id]`?

Comment: Show the `form_for` or `form_tag` you are using in the view for `StoriesController#view`.

Comment: Also, in `new`, in `@keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])`, what are the params you are receving? Show that as well. I suppose the `@keynote` is also nil in this case?

Comment: @Zabba I added the code of new.html.erb for StoriesController.
In `new`in `@keynote = Keynote.find(params[:keynote_id])` the parameters are being passed correctly, I tried printing the Keynote attributes in the `new` view and it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'keynote_id', @keynote.id  %>
    .
    rest of the form stuff here
    .
<% end %>
```

PS. Not sure if you will get the `keynote_id` in `params[:keynote_id]` or `params[:story][:keynote_id]` .. check out both.

NB: I think there would be a easier way to do it too, using `fields_for` or something similar, but I don't have access to a Rails setup at the moment to test that out.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the error on that line but then it fails on the next one with the following error:
NoMethodError in StoriesController#create
undefined method `keynote' for #<User:0x007fba0e4a40c8>.

If I remove `keynote` it throws this error but the Story is actually being created, without the keynote_id though: `No route matches {:controller=>"stories"}`

That looks like a routing error. What am I missing? I posted the routes file above.

Comment: Add that as a separate question :) On SO, when an answer helps you, it is the custom to accept that answer by clicking the tickmark next to it. Also one can show appreciation by up-voting an answer. See [here for some info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!

Comment: thanks man, just accepted your answer but I can't vote it up yet since I don't have enough reputation. I'll add that other question in a few minutes.

Comment: This is the other related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022587/nomethoderror-in-controlleraction-undefined-method-keynote-for-user0x007

Could you have a look at it please? Thanks!